# Vapor 3 - Trying to map Login request with model that does not exits in database

Tags: swift, database, vapor

I am trying to implement a simple login request API. 
As you can see in the coding sample below, I have `LoginRequest` which is the data I get from the client (iOS, Android etc). With this I check if `User` exists in the DB, then I check if the user's password is correct.

However, what I am struggling with is how do I return a model that doesn't exist in the DB. In the example below I have `LoginResponse`. I don't want to reveal the full `User` & `AuthToken` (models in DB) data to the client, hence I have create the `LoginResponse` model. The only data i want to reveal to the client is the `LoginResponse`'s `authToken` if everything was successful.

What I expect from the user: username and password

```swift
struct LoginRequest : Codable, Content {
    var username: String
    var password : String
}
```

The response I give back to the user: success (with authToken), incorrect password or user doesn't exists.

```swift
/// Response model for user login.
struct LoginResponse : Codable, Content {

    enum LoginResultType : String, Codable {
        case success
        case incorrectPassword
        case noUser
    }

    var authToken : String?
    var state : LoginResultType

    init(state : LoginResultType) {
        authToken  = nil
        self.state = state
    }
}}
```

```swift
func login(_ req : Request) throws -> Future<LoginResponse> {
        return try req.content.decode(LoginRequest.self).flatMap(to: LoginResponse.self) { loginRequest in
            return User.query(on: req).filter(\.username == loginRequest.username)
                .first().map(to: LoginResponse.self) { user in

                    /// check if we have found a user, if not then return LoginResponse with noUser
                    guard let u = user else {
                        return LoginResponse(state: .noUser)
                    }
                    /// if the password isn't the same, then we tell the user
                    /// that the password is incorrect.
                    if u.password != loginRequest.password {
                        return LoginResponse(state: . incorrectPassword)
                    }


                    /// If username and password are the same then we create a random authToken and save this to the DB.
/// Then I need to return LoginResponse with success and authToken.
                    let authToken = AuthToken(token: "<Random number>")
                    authToken.user = u.id
                    return authToken.create(on: req).flatMap(to: LoginResponse.self){ auth in
                        var lr       = LoginResponse(state: .success)
                        lr.authToken = auth.token
                        return lr
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

The coding below is a headache, this will not let me return a LoginResponse after I have created a new authToken in the DB.

```swift
                    return authToken.create(on: req).flatMap(to: LoginResponse.self){ auth in
                        var lr       = LoginResponse(state: .success)
                        lr.authToken = auth.token
                        return lr
                    }
```

Once I have created an authToken I want to reveal the authToken in the LoginResponse model with success state, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map` instead of `flatMap`.

`map` - to return something non-future

`flatMap` - to return Future

And also you could return some object as a future using

```swift
req.eventLoop.newSucceededFuture(result: someObject)
```

Code below should work like a charm

```swift
func login(_ req : Request) throws -> Future<LoginResponse> {
    return try req.content.decode(LoginRequest.self).flatMap { loginRequest in
        return User.query(on: req).filter(\.username == loginRequest.username).first().flatMap { user in
                    /// check if we have found a user, if not then return LoginResponse with noUser
            guard let u = user else {
                return req.eventLoop.newSucceededFuture(result: LoginResponse(state: .noUser))
            }
            /// if the password isn't the same, then we tell the user
            /// that the password is incorrect.
            if u.password != loginRequest.password {
                return req.eventLoop.newSucceededFuture(result: LoginResponse(state: .incorrectPassword))
            }
            /// If username and password are the same then we create a random authToken and save this to the DB.
            /// Then I need to return LoginResponse with success and authToken.
            let authToken = AuthToken(token: "<Random number>")
            authToken.user = u.id
            return authToken.create(on: req).map { auth in
                var lr = LoginResponse(state: .success)
                lr.authToken = auth.token
                return lr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But to be honest it's a bad practice to return errors with `200 OK` http code.

The best practice is to use HTTP codes for errors instead, and Vapor uses this way by design.

So your code may look simply like this

```swift
struct LoginResponse: Content {
    let authToken: String?
}
```

```swift
func login(_ req : Request) throws -> Future<LoginResponse> {
    return try req.content.decode(LoginRequest.self).flatMap { loginRequest in
        return User.query(on: req).filter(\.username == loginRequest.username).first().flatMap { user in
            /// check if we have found a user, if not then throw 404
            guard let u = user else {
                throw Abort(.notFound, reason: "User not found")
            }
            /// if the password isn't the same, then throw 400
            if u.password != loginRequest.password {
                throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Incorrect password")
            }
            /// If username and password are the same then we create a random authToken and save this to the DB.
            /// Then I need to return LoginResponse with success and authToken.
            let authToken = AuthToken(token: "<Random number>")
            authToken.user = u.id
            return authToken.create(on: req).map { auth in
                var lr = LoginResponse(state: .success)
                lr.authToken = auth.token
                return lr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks clean and there is no need to parse additional enum on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, never seen newSucceededFuture before. I’ll give this a try in the morning. 

Comment: And also you could to take a look at `CodyFire` lib for iOS, it's awesome to use it together with Vapor, it was designed for it and inspired by it.

Comment: Cheers for that mate, I’ll experiment CodyFire, looking at the doc it looks fairly straightforward